# Google sheets formula needed to return value based on 1 of 3 values in column A and 1 of 2 values in column B

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns: Column B has 3 possible values: 1, 2, 3 to select from. Column C has 2 possible values: "Yes" and "No". I need an IF (or IFS?) formula that will return a different value based on all 6 possible combinations, e.g.

```
1 Yes
1 No
2 Yes
2 No
3 Yes
3 No
```

The following formula works if Column B only offered one possible value to choose from:

=IF(AND(B2=1,C2="No"),SUM(50+0),SUM(50+10))

But again, the user may need to select a "2" or a "3" from the dropdown in Column B.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have headers in B1 and C1 and that your "1,2,3" or "Yes,No" data runs B2:C, clear Column D entirely (including any header) and place the following formula in D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IF((B2:B="") + (C2:C=""),, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&C2:C, {"1Yes","Val1"; "1No","Val2"; "2Yes","Val3"; "2No","Val4"; "3Yes","Val5"; "3No","Val6"}, 2, FALSE)))})`

This formula will create the header text (which you can change as you like within the formula) and all results for the column.

If the Col-B or Col-C cell is blank, null will be returned (since there is not enough data to find a matching return).

Otherwise, a concatenation of the Col-B and Col-C cell (e.g., `1Yes`, `3No`, etc.) will be formed, and `VLOOKUP` will look for that combination within a virtual array containing each possible combination and a value, returning the value (i.e., element 2).

Just change `Val1`, `Val2`, etc. within the formula to the actual values that you want returned for each combination listed before it. Remember to keep string results in quotes, while any returns that you want to be numeric should *not* be enclosed in quotes

You may also enter formulaic expressions in place of `Val1`, `Val2`, etc. But understand that if you want to use cell values from Col B or Col C in those expressions, they should be listed as `B2:B` or `C2:C` rather than any single-cell reference.

The `IFERROR` wrap is just standard practice. If anyone were to somehow enter something other than "1,2,3" or "Yes/No" in the respective cells, null would be returned rather than an unsightly error.

NOTE: You could also use `SWITCH` in place of `VLOOKUP`:

`=ArrayFormula({"Header"; IF((B2:B="") + (C2:C=""),, IFERROR(SWITCH(B2:B&C2:C, "1Yes", "Val1", "1No", "Val2", "2Yes", "Val3", "2No", "Val4", "3Yes", "Val5", "3No", "Val6")))})`